Splash screen on iOS in MAUI project is always white screen
I'm trying to set a splash screen in a MAUI app project which compatible with Android and iOS
in the android app, I've managed to set up the splash screen as I wanted
but in the iOS app, no matter what I do, the splash screen is always just a white screen
I've set LaunchScreen.storyboard in the Platforms/iOS folder, defined the LaunchScreen in the info.plist file
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>

also in the csproj file of the project configured the LaunchScreen storyboard file
<ItemGroup>
    <InterfaceDefinition Include="Platforms\iOS\LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
</ItemGroup>

the storyboard file I've create and configured on XCode project and just copied it to the MAUI project on my pc
Here is the LaunchScreen.storyboard file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="22505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="22504"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.20784313725490194" green="0.52941176470588236" blue="0.92156862745098034" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nP3-5F-Xa6" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="OqC-ur-BJj"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nP3-5F-Xa6" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="centerY" id="h6i-LG-hb0"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="splash_icon" width="192" height="192"/>
    </resources>
</document>

anyone maybe go a working solution?

What is the splash screen supposed to show? Just the image? Do you also include the image in your project somehow? If you make the LaunchScreen background a different color, does that show up? Then you at least know that that is included correctly and you just dont see the image. Do you exclude the MauiSplashscreen node for iOS?

@GeraldVersluis for starters I'm trying just to change the background color of the ios splash screen, once it would work i just want to add the app's icon image as static image
I haven't excluded the MauiSplashScreen node for iOS, is it needed?

I think that is needed, else the MauiSplashscreen will also generate a LaunchScreen and it will override what you are putting in there.

@GeraldVersluis hallelujah!
I've been struggling with it for 3 days, finally working, at least with the background color change
now I'm trying to include the image also
I'll update on it

Glad to help! Let me write something in the form of an answer for reference :)

To use a native splash screen you will have to make sure that you disable the MauiSplashScreen functionality for that platform.
You can do this in multiple ways, but in its simplest form add a condition to the MauiSplashScreen node in your csproj file like below:
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) != 'ios'" />

This will exclude the splash screen generation from .NET MAUI but only for iOS.
The things you already had was:

Create a storyboard file

Design that through Xcode

Include it in your .NET MAUI project, can be anywhere but probably Platforms/iOS/Resources makes most sense

Add the entry in the info.plist file:
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>


Make sure that the LaunchScreen.storyboard file has the right build action. Technically that should happen automatically if you put it in the Platforms/iOS/Resources folder if not, or if you want to put it elsewhere, include this in your csproj:
<ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">
    <InterfaceDefinition Include="Platforms\iOS\Resources\LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
</ItemGroup>


If you want to include an image in your LaunchScreen, make sure to just use the filename only and reference that from your LaunchScreen. Then add your image as a BundleResource in your .NET MAUI project.


All of this I also have in a video here.
